# How do I get a refresh token for command line gsutil to work?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I use gsutil to transfer files from a Windows machine to Google Cloud Storage.

I have not used it for more than 6 months and now when I try it I get:

Failure: invalid_grant

From researching this I suspect the access token is no longer valid as it has not been used for 6 months, and I need a refresh token?

I cannot seem to find how to get and use this.

thanks

Running `gsutil -DD config` produces the following output:

```
C:\Python27>python c:/gsutil/gsutil -DD config 

DEBUG:boto:path=/pub/gsutil.tar.gz
DEBUG:boto:auth_path=/pub/gsutil.tar.gz
DEBUG:boto:Method: HEAD
DEBUG:boto:Path: /pub/gsutil.tar.gz
DEBUG:boto:Data:
DEBUG:boto:Headers: {}
DEBUG:boto:Host: storage.googleapis.com
DEBUG:boto:Params: {}
DEBUG:boto:establishing HTTPS connection: host=storage.googleapis.com, kwargs={'timeout': 70}
DEBUG:boto:Token: None
DEBUG:oauth2_client:GetAccessToken: checking cache for key *******************************
DEBUG:oauth2_client:FileSystemTokenCache.GetToken: key=******************************* not present (cache_file= c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\2\oauth2_client-tokencache._.ea******************************)
DEBUG:oauth2_client:GetAccessToken: token from cache: None
DEBUG:oauth2_client:GetAccessToken: fetching fresh access token...
INFO:oauth2client.client:Refreshing access_token connect: (accounts.google.com, 443) 
send: 'POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: accounts.google.com\r\nContent-Length: 177\r\ncontent-type: application/x- www-form-urlencoded\r\naccept-encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nuser-agent: Python-httplib2/0.7.7 (gzip)\r\n\r\nclient_secret=******************&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=****************************************&client_ id=****************.apps.googleusercontent.com' reply: 'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n' 
header: Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 header: Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate header: Pragma: no-cache header: Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT header: Date: Thu, 08 May 2014 02:02:21 GMT header: Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="json.txt"; filename*=UTF-8''json.txt header: Content-Encoding: gzip header: X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff header: X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
header: X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block header: Server: GSE header: Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic header: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
INFO:oauth2client.client:Failed to retrieve access token: { "error" : "invalid_grant" } 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/gsutil/gsutil", line 83, in <module> gslib.__main__.main() File "c:\gsutil\gslib_main_.py", line 151, in main command_runner.RunNamedCommand('ver', ['-l']) 
  File "c:\gsutil\gslib\command_runner.py", line 95, in RunNamedCommand self._MaybeCheckForAndOfferSoftwareUpdate(command_name, debug)):
  File "c:\gsutil\gslib\command_runner.py", line 181, in _MaybeCheckForAndOfferSoftwareUpdate cur_ver = LookUpGsutilVersion(suri_builder.StorageUri(GSUTIL_PUB_TARBALL)) 
  File "c:\gsutil\gslib\util.py", line 299, in LookUpGsutilVersion obj = uri.get_key(False) 
  File "c:\gsutil\third_party\boto\boto\storage_uri.py", line 342, in get_key generation=self.generation) 
  File "c:\gsutil\third_party\boto\boto\gs\bucket.py", line 102, in get_key query_args_l=query_args_l) 
  File "c:\gsutil\third_party\boto\boto\s3\bucket.py", line 176, in _get_key_internal query_args=query_args) 
  File "c:\gsutil\third_party\boto\boto\s3\connection.py", line 547, in make_request retry_handler=retry_handler 
  File "c:\gsutil\third_party\boto\boto\connection.py", line 947, in make_request retry_handler=retry_handler) 
  File "c:\gsutil\third_party\boto\boto\connection.py", line 838, in _mexe request.authorize(connection=self) 
  File "c:\gsutil\third_party\boto\boto\connection.py", line 377, in authorize connection._auth_handler.add_auth(self, *********) 
  File "c:\gsutil\gslib\third_party\oauth2_plugin\oauth2_plugin.py", line 22, in add_auth self.oauth2_client.GetAuthorizationHeader() 
  File "c:\gsutil\gslib\third_party\oauth2_plugin\oauth2_client.py", line 338, in GetAuthorizationHeader return 'Bearer %s' % self.GetAccessToken().token 
  File "c:\gsutil\gslib\third_party\oauth2_plugin\oauth2_client.py", line 309, in GetAccessToken access_token = self.FetchAccessToken() 
  File "c:\gsutil\gslib\third_party\oauth2_plugin\oauth2_client.py", line 435, in FetchAccessToken credentials.refresh(http) 
  File "c:\gsutil\third_party\google-api-python-client\oauth2client\client.py", line 516, in refresh self._refresh(http.request) 
  File "c:\gsutil\third_party\google-api-python-client\oauth2client\client.py", line 653, in _refresh self._do_refresh_request(http_request) 
  File "c:\gsutil\third_party\google-api-python-client\oauth2client\client.py", line 710, in _do_refresh_request raise AccessTokenRefreshError(error_msg) oauth2client.client.AccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_grant
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brandon Yarbrough gave me suggestions which solved this problem. He suspected that the .boto file was corrupted and suggested I delete it and run gsutil config again. I did this and it solved the problem.

Comment: FYI: the current version of gsutil is not vulnerable to this problem.

Answer (score 5):

You can ask gsutil to configure itself. Go to the directory with gsutil and run this:

```
c:\gsutil> python gsutil config
```

Gsutil will lead you through the steps to setting up your credentials.

That said, access tokens only normally last about a half hour. It's more likely that the previously-configured refresh token was revoked for some reason. Alternately, you can only request new tokens at a certain rate. It's possible your account has been requesting many, many refresh tokens for some reason and has been temporarily rate limited by the access service.

Comment: thanks Brandon - I tried config yesterday and got:

C:\gsutil>python gsutil config
Failure: invalid_grant.

I just tried it again and strangely I got:

C:\Python27>python c:/gsutil/gsutil config
Failure: Unable to find the server at accounts.google.com.

Comment: That's odd. Is it still happening? Are you perhaps behind a firewall that prevents you from accessing accounts.google.com? Can you view this URL with a web browser on that machine: https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en

Comment: Hi Brandon - yes, I can access the accounts url with Chrome, using my login.

Comment: using C:\Python27>python c:/gsutil/gsutil config - I now am back to getting invalid_grant

Comment: Could you try again using `gsutil -DD config` and post the results into your question? There will probably be a few lines in it that include "Authorization: SomeLongStringOfStuff". Make sure to remove those lines before posting.

Comment: C:\Python27>python c:/gsutil/gsutil -DD config  DEBUG:boto:path=/pub/gsutil.tar.gz  DEBUG:boto:auth_path=/pub/gsutil.tar.gz  DEBUG:boto:Method: HEAD  DEBUG:boto:Path: /pub/gsutil.tar.gz  DEBUG:boto:Data:  DEBUG:boto:Headers: {}  DEBUG:boto:Host: storage.googleapis.com  DEBUG:boto:Params: {}  DEBUG:boto:establishing HTTPS connection: host=storage.googleapis.com, kwargs={'timeout': 70}  DEBUG:boto:Token: None  DEBUG:oauth2_client:GetAccessToken: checking cache for key *******************************  DEBUG:oauth2_client:FileSystemTokenCache.GetToken: key=*******************************

Comment: not present (cache_file=  c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\2\oauth2_client-tokencache._.ea******************************)  DEBUG:oauth2_client:GetAccessToken: token from cache: None  DEBUG:oauth2_client:GetAccessToken: fetching fresh access token...  INFO:oauth2client.client:Refreshing access_token  connect: (accounts.google.com, 443)

Comment: send: 'POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: accounts.google.com\r\nContent-Length: 177\r\ncontent-type: application/x-  www-form-urlencoded\r\naccept-encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nuser-agent: Python-httplib2/0.7.7 (gzip)\r\n\r\nclient_secret=******************&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=****************************************&client_  id=****************.apps.googleusercontent.com'  reply: 'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n'

Comment: header: Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8  header: Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate  header: Pragma: no-cache  header: Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT  header: Date: Thu, 08 May 2014 02:02:21 GMT  header: Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="json.txt"; filename*=UTF-8''json.txt  header: Content-Encoding: gzip  header: X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff  header: X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

Comment: header: X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block  header: Server: GSE  header: Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic  header: Transfer-Encoding: chunked  INFO:oauth2client.client:Failed to retrieve access token: {    "error" : "invalid_grant"  }  Traceback (most recent call last):    File "c:/gsutil/gsutil", line 83, in <module>      gslib.__main__.main()    File "c:\gsutil\gslib\__main__.py", line 151, in main      command_runner.RunNamedCommand('ver', ['-l'])    File "c:\gsutil\gslib\command_runner.py", line 95, in RunNamedCommand      self._MaybeCheckForAndOfferSoftwareUpdate(command_name, debug)):

Comment: File "c:\gsutil\gslib\command_runner.py", line 181, in _MaybeCheckForAndOfferSoftwareUpdate      cur_ver = LookUpGsutilVersion(suri_builder.StorageUri(GSUTIL_PUB_TARBALL))    File "c:\gsutil\gslib\util.py", line 299, in LookUpGsutilVersion      obj = uri.get_key(False)    File "c:\gsutil\third_party\boto\boto\storage_uri.py", line 342, in get_key      generation=self.generation)    File "c:\gsutil\third_party\boto\boto\gs\bucket.py", line 102, in get_key      query_args_l=query_args_l)    File "c:\gsutil\third_party\boto\boto\s3\bucket.py", line 176, in _get_key_internal

Comment: uery_args=query_args)    File "c:\gsutil\third_party\boto\boto\s3\connection.py", line 547, in make_request      retry_handler=retry_handler    File "c:\gsutil\third_party\boto\boto\connection.py", line 947, in make_request      retry_handler=retry_handler)    File "c:\gsutil\third_party\boto\boto\connection.py", line 838, in _mexe      request.authorize(connection=self)    File "c:\gsutil\third_party\boto\boto\connection.py", line 377, in authorize

Comment: connection._auth_handler.add_auth(self, *********)    File "c:\gsutil\gslib\third_party\oauth2_plugin\oauth2_plugin.py", line 22, in add_auth      self.oauth2_client.GetAuthorizationHeader()    File "c:\gsutil\gslib\third_party\oauth2_plugin\oauth2_client.py", line 338, in GetAuthorizationHeader      return 'Bearer %s' % self.GetAccessToken().token    File "c:\gsutil\gslib\third_party\oauth2_plugin\oauth2_client.py", line 309, in GetAccessToken      access_token = self.FetchAccessToken()

Comment: File "c:\gsutil\gslib\third_party\oauth2_plugin\oauth2_client.py", line 435, in FetchAccessToken      credentials.refresh(http)    File "c:\gsutil\third_party\google-api-python-client\oauth2client\client.py", line 516, in refresh      self._refresh(http.request)    File "c:\gsutil\third_party\google-api-python-client\oauth2client\client.py", line 653, in _refresh      self._do_refresh_request(http_request)    File "c:\gsutil\third_party\google-api-python-client\oauth2client\client.py", line 710, in _do_refresh_request

Comment: raise AccessTokenRefreshError(error_msg)  oauth2client.client.AccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_grant

Comment: Okay, here's a suggestion. I think the refresh token in your .boto file is bad for some reason (presumably revoked). I suspect if you delete the .boto file and then run config, it should solve your problem. If not, I suspect you're running a very old version of gsutil. You may want to update to a newer version. There have been a lot of bug fixes over the last year, one of which may solve your problem.

Comment: Awesome! I found and deleted (or rather renamed) the .boto file. When I ran config again it worked fine and created a new .boto file. Now running gsutil to transfer files is back to normal. I have also updated it to the newest version of gsutil. Thanks Brandon for all your help with this.

Answer (score 3):

The command to authenticate is now

```
$ gcloud auth login
```

That should refresh your grant and get you going again.

You may also want to run

```
$ gcloud components update
```

to update your installation.